# Horizontal part and vertical part of tangent bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was reading

Lakehal Belarbi, Hichem Elhendi, "[On the geometry of the tangent
bundle with gradient Sasaki metric](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/AJMS-11-2020-0125/full/pdf?title=on-the-geometry-of-the-tangent-bundle-with-gradient-sasaki-metric)",

and there was something I couldn't understand.

It was written that $T_{(t,u)}TM$ can be decomposed into vertical and horizontal parts ,

$$ V_{(x,u)} := \ker (d \pi _{(x,u)}) = \{a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}|_{(x,u)} \mid a^i \in \mathbb R\} \\ H_{(x,u)} := \{a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} |_{(x,y)} - a^i y^i \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}|_{(x,u)} \mid a^i \in \mathbb R\} \quad.$$

I have no idea where $H$ comes from. Could you help me derive this.

Comment: It comes from the metric and associated connection.

Comment: An element $v\in T_uTM$ is horizontal iff it is the velocity of a parallel vector field along a curve.

Comment: Thank you!! I understand it!!